# I can send data to a template page on form submission. but pagination not working properly

Tags: theming

The module file:

```
<?php
function BM_weather_API_part2_theme() {
  return array(
    'BM_weather_API_part2' => array(
      'template' => 'BM_weather_API_part2',
      'variables' => array('msg' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

function BM_weather_API_part2_menu() {    
  $items['weather/report'] = array(
    'title' => 'Weather API - Part 2',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('BM_weather_API_part2_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'BM_weather_API_part2.pages.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}

.inc

 function BM_weather_API_part2_form() {
  $form['location_name'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Location',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  if (!empty($form_state['BM_weather_API_part2']['weather_result'])) {
    $form['result'] = array(
      '#markup' => $form_state['BM_weather_API_part2']['weather_result'],
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Get the weather report',
    '#validate' => array('BM_weather_API_part2_form_validate'),
    '#submit' => array('BM_weather_API_part2_form_submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function BM_weather_API_part2_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (BM_weather_API_part2_check_location($form_state['values']['location_name'])) {
    $form_state['BM_weather_API_part2']['weather_result'] = FALSE;
    form_set_error('location_name', t('Please enter a proper location name.'));
  }
}

function BM_weather_API_part2_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $query = db_select('hello', 'w')
      ->fields('w', array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f',
    'g',
  ))
    $table_sort = $query->extend('TableSort') // Add table sort extender.
      ->orderBy('g','ASC');
    $pager = $table_sort->extend('PagerDefault')
      ->limit(10);
  $records = $pager->execute();
rows = array();
foreach ($records as $val) {
$p = $val -> a;
rows[] = array($p);
}
$value = array('rows' => $rows);
$output = theme('BM_weather_API_part2', array(
    'msg' => $value));
$output .= theme('pager', array('quantity',count($rows)));
  $form_state['BM_weather_API_part2']['weather_result'] = $output;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function BM_weather_API_part2_get_weather($loc) {
  // ...
}

.tpl

<div id="message">
    <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>something</th></tr>
        <?php
        for($i=0;$i<count($msg['rows']);$i++) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>' . $msg['rows'][$i][0]. '</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
}
       ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here I'm able to call `tpl` and also pagination is showing but when I click next in pagination, the page reload and no data is showing and pagination disappears.

Comment: the problem seems to because of reloading the page.. anbody know how to add ajax call for pagination of the same???